# Текстовые строки и NULL

Tags: строки, null, любой-язык

Нынче вечер пятницы, поэтому мой вопрос не практического, а сугубо философского свойства, для потрепаться. Каких-то материалов наверняка можно нагуглить, но гуглить неохота, хочется поговорить.

Есть такая концепция — NULL-значения. Смысл: значение отсутствует, неизвестно, не имеет смысла и т.п.

Если речь идёт, например, о дате рождения, то заданная дата — это дата рождения, а NULL означает, что даты рождения гражданина мы по той или иной причине не знаем. Ну или что он ещё не родился, сидит у мамы в животе.

При этом числовой 0 и NULL несут разную смысловую нагрузку. Если речь идёт, например, о сумме денег на банковских счетах гражданина, то 0 может означать, что денег у него нет, а NULL — что мы не знаем, сколько у него денег (не посчитали пока).

Во многих случаях NULL неприменим. Например, в банковском софте в записи о банковском счёте сумма всегда известна точно — какой же это банк, если он сам не знает, сколько на счёте денег?

Сказанное выше давно известно, это была прелюдия к вопросу. А вопрос такой:

**Если у нас текстовое поле, то в каких случаях пустая строка и NULL несут разную смысловую нагрузку?**

Я думал и не смог придумать ни одного практически применимого примера. Складывается впечатление, что пустой текст и NULL во всех случаях должны рассматриваться как эквиваленты.

Если позволить себе немного пофилософствовать, то я считаю, причина в том, что текст — это очень особенный тип, в максимально общем виде выражающий древнюю, докомпьютерную идею письменности. Вот у нас чистая восковая дощечка, на ней ни хрена нет, пусто. А потом мы на ней чего-то накарябали стилом и теперь у нас есть текст. Легко заметить, что «пустой текст» и «отсутствие текста» не различаются никак. Текст выпадает из состояния «отсутствует» только тогда, когда в нём появляется хотя бы один символ.

Здесь уместно возразить, что NULL может обозначать отсутствие самой восковой дощечки, однако, возвращаясь к информационным технологиям XXI века, хочется спросить: есть ли примеры, где это нужно?

А что вы думаете про эквивалентность NULL-а и пустой строки? В каких случаях пустая строка и NULL несут разную смысловую нагрузку?

Интересны любые примеры и соображения.

P.S. Речь, понятно, не только про классические SQL-СУБД, но про систему типов и значений в целом, где бы она ни применялась.

Comment: NULL не используется в текстовых полях! В тексте NULL будет считатся строкой длина которой 4 символа.  
В основном он служит для инициализации переменных.

int a; // Если переменная "а" не будет не где задействована будет ругаться компилятор.


int a=NULL; // а так ругани не будет

Comment: В сожалению, вы ошибаетесь.
Вот обсуждается вопрос эквивалентный заданному мной: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3000812/varchar-columns-nullable-or-not
Вот обсуждение NULL в Oracle, где указывается, что Oracle провозгласил эквивалентность NULL и пустой строки: http://habrahabr.ru/post/127327/

(да, я не удержался и залез в Яндекс!)

Comment: Ну мир разработчиков ПО не только одним Oracle един, у большинства производителей компиляторов это не так! Глупо пологатся на данные одного вендора!

Comment: Вы, наверное, подумали, что я говорю о null-овых указателях и ссылках на объекты. А речь идёт о совершенно иной концепции. Для понимания вам, наверное, стоит познакомиться с вот этой статьёй: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/NULL_(SQL)

Answer (score 4):

> Если у нас текстовое поле, то в каких случаях пустая строка и NULL несут разную смысловую нагрузку?

Пустая строка - это строка, в которой нет символов. NULL - это вообще ничего. Если мы запросили перевод токена и получили пустую строку, значит токен непереводим. Если мы запросили перевод и результат - NULL, значит этим токеном никто не озаботился, и впору кидать эксепшен.

Comment: Ну т.е. вы предлагаете использовать NULL в качестве индикатора исключительной ситуации. Подход в целом имеет право на жизнь, если ошибка может случиться ровно одна. Если же их может быть хотя бы две, надо в той или иной форме возвращать информацию о том, что случилось — исключением ли, кодом возврата ли, спец.объектом ли… NULL не выглядит адекватным решением, так, изолента, чтобы подмотать по-быстрому. Почему NULL, почему не булев результат успех/ошибка?

Comment: @Пётр Таран, а вот и нет, это вы придумали, что null - это индикатор исключительной ситуации. null - это ничего; перевода нет - вернулось ничего. Это не обязательно исключительная ситуация.

Comment: Ну т.е. нет перевода — NULL, токен непереводим — пустая строка. В целом да, логика тут есть. Но, лично на мой вкус, такой подход лишён понятности. По мне бы лучше не различать пустоту/NULL, а вернуть доп.код, который явным образом скажет: переведено как надо, непереводимо, нет перевода. Оно и в коде смотрится наглядней и расширить легко, если будут какие-то другие ситуации.

Answer (score 4):

Очень простой пример из жизни баз данных. База данных какой-нибудь больницы.

Поле "отчество" допускает состояние пустоты >null<.

Мы можем ничего не знать об отчестве от пациента (если он без сознания и без документов), тогда это >null<.

И пациент по документам может не иметь отчества - ну, пусто у него в графе "отец". Или он принадлежит народности, где отчеств не бывает. Тогда в базу пишется не >null<, а пустая строка - мы *знаем*, что отчество есть, и знаем, что оно - пустое.

Answer (score 3):

Да в куче случаев пустая строка и NULL могут иметь разный смысл.

Например, текст инструкции. Если его не загрузили (еще не поместили в систему) -- NULL, а если просто сам текст отсутствует -- пустая строка.

И позицию Oracle тоже понять можно. Все же SQL концептуально декларативный, а не процедурный язык, поэтому эквивалентность пустой строки и NULL может здорово облегчить жизнь разработчиков.

Comment: Как это — пустой текст инструкции? Ни разу в жизни не встречал инструкций с пустым текстом.

Comment: Если чего-то не видел, это не значит, что такого не бывает.

Comment: Я вот пытаюсь понять: это вы мне хамите или просто сами пример привести не можете?

Comment: Ну, что Вы, конечно же нет. Просто я сам, бывает, забываю, что так и не написал текст инструкции (или чего-то вроде).

Вот открывает человек файл, а там пусто...

Answer (score 3):

NULL очень удобен именно как признак того, что у переменной вообще нет никакого значения, даже пустого. Например, для организации мемоизации.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char* txt = NULL;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        if (txt == NULL) { txt = "Hello World!"; }
        puts(txt);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: char* txt = "";
Чем хуже?

Comment: Тем, что это вполне валидная строка. И как мы отличим две ситуации:

1. строковая переменная не проинициализирована
2. строковая переменная проинициализирована пустой строкой

Это даже по моему примеру видно. Вот такой код:

    if (strlen(txt) == 0) { txt = ""; }

сделает 10 присваиваний. Очевидно, такой простой код я выбрал для иллюстрации принципа. В реальной жизни вместо присваивания может быть тяжелая формула, запрос к базе данных, скачивание данных из интернета и т.д. и т.п. Вот откуда берутся жутко тормознутые программы...

Comment: К сожалению, за простотой иллюстрации принципа потерялся сам принцип. Вы тут просто используете особенность хранения сишных строк и делаете акцент на производительности. Если мы заменим char* на std::string, то выигрыша уже не будет, т.к. для различения пустоты и NULL-а придётся std::string делать динамическим. Но производительность — третий вопрос. Интересней, в каких случаях осмысленный ответ (тяжелая формула, запрос к базе данных, скачивание данных из интернета) является пустой строкой.

Comment: Вы совершаете распространенную логическую ошибку. Вы требуете доказательства, что "" может быть осмысленным ответом. Я не обязан это доказывать. Для меня достаточно того, что NULL не может быть осмысленным ответом (как текст). Почитайте - https://clck.ru/9SsX2

Вот еще пример, когда NULL может быть полезен, не далее как вчера столкнулся, когда писал функцию, возвращающую списки (итератор не устраивал). Допустим, функция возвращает строки, списки... Как понять, что они кончились? Да возвратить NULL! Пустая строка не подходит, она запросто может встретиться там, откуда читаем. В файле, например

Answer (score 0):

А в чём филосовское различие NULL(SQL) и null(нулевой указатель)? Судя по статье, в том, что операции сравнения по-разному определены. То есть

```
NULL == NULL; // возвращает NULL или UNKNOWN
null == null; // возвращает `true`
```

Отсюда и филосовская разница для строк. Две пустые строки - одно и то же. Два значения `NULL` - разные вещи.

Если надо проверить, что две строки (из внешних данных) равны, лучше использовать концепцию пустых строк, а не `NULL`.

Comment: Ну несравнимость двух NULL-ов между собой — это всё же особенности персонально SQL. Вопрос: равен ли один «нихренанет» другому «нихренанет» — это очень глубокая философия, 37-й уровень, не меньше! Интересней понять, в каких ситуациях надо различать пустую строку и NULL.

Answer (score 0):

Когда из БД тянем несколько десятков параметров и объединяем их в одну строку, гораздо проще заранее сохранять их там (в случае отсутствия данных) в виде пустой строки (""), чем потом, перед объединением, каждый параметр проверять на то, что он не NULL.
Dim fio As String = "Муслиев" & "Колабельды" & ""
Меньше возни с исключениями...